# What is this Java program behaviour? Why does this not give a compile time error of `Incompatible type cannot convert int to string`?

Tags: java

Why does this not give a compile time error of `Incompatible type cannot convert int to string`? also why main method have one- dimension String array, but not other type array?

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = new String[3];
        a[0] = "10";
        a[1] = "20";
        a[2] = "30";

        for(String x : a) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that you should search more (if you atleast did) before posting questions about basics. I also suggest that you learn java with some documentation/book/anything that details how java works precisely. It may be a bit more harsh than just trying things, but that's how you can learn.

Comment: typing "Incompatible type cannot convert int to string." on google would probably lead you to an answer. If not, reading some book/guide/doc would for sure.

Comment: Where exactly do you think this would happen? Why?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code, can you post the whole console output.

Comment: It doesn't give that error because the only int in that code (the 3 in `new String[3]`) really does need to be an int; no such conversion is needed.

Answer (score 2):

His question was why does this **not** give the error.

You have created a String array and you are assigning Strings to it so there is no problem. Just because those Strings have numbers in them doesn't stop them from being Strings.

If you removed the quotes, you *would* get an error. In the following example, you'd be trying put ints into a String array, and it would not compile.

E.g.

```
    String[] a = new String[3];
    a[0] = 10;
    a[1] = 20;
    a[2] = 30;
```